# Read XML file from any location not fixed location (Internal/External) on Android (4.2.2 or 5.0.1)device because of commercial handling

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Read XML file from any location not fixed location (Internal/External) on Android device

I have tried by myself but has only found methods that can read media file like image,audio,video on anroid device.
so my requirement is clear about reading xml file in android device.

I want to read xml file from any location (internal/External) of android device by browsing it

we have trired this one but it allows only image,audio,video..

```
string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
            using (var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
            {
                if (cursor == null) return path;
                var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
            }
            return path;
```

Any help will be highly appropriated.

Comment: you cannot use media store to access xml, media store stores meta data of media files only.

Comment: So can you please explain me what can i use to read xml file from any location (internal/External) .

Comment: What do you mean by "read XML file from any location"?

Comment: System.IO.File methods

Comment: So can you please explain me what can i use to read xml file